# Script for Moving 50 Rows to the Next Column - Excel

Tags: excel

I have a request for how I might go about the following operation:

I have a csv file (that I'm opening in Excel) that I am appending a block of data 50X2 (rowsXcolumns) to the csv file. With the finished csv file, I would like to automate a process where every 50 rows get selected (both columns) and the data essentially gets cut and copied to the next two available columns.

An example would be data from $A$1:$B$50 is in the csv and then a second sample is taken and the second set of data goes to $A$51:$B$100 and I would like to automatically move the second set to $C$1:$D$50 and perform that move for all samples taken.

I don't know what the best route for this operation would be (macro/VBA/etc) and would like some assistance with this, if it is easily possible.

Thank you all for your time and help.

Comment: moving pattern is still unclear... what should happen with `$C$1:$D$50` array when a new block is added, and so on?

Comment: Sorry if it was confusing. Let's say there are 4 samples of data total. They would be written as `$A1:$B200` with each sample consisting of 50 rows (2 columns wide) of data. I would like the outcome of the script/macro/etc to be the first sample staying in `$A$1:$B$50`, the second going to `$C$1:$D$50`, the third going to `$E$1:$F$50`, and the last going to `$G$1:$H$50`. I would like this to work regardless of the number of samples that were taken. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea behind what needs to be done is:

- Get the number of new columns to make (e.g. `Total Rows/#rows per column`)
- For each new column to make, cut from the `nth + 1` row to the last row, where `nth` row is the number of rows per column that you want (in your case, 50).
- Paste the cut rows to the right of the last column that has data in it
- Repeat until all columns have been made

Here is some sample code that I put together to get you started. This assumes your data starts in cell A1, and that each column should contain a maxium of 10 rows. You can change the `rowsToSkip` value to meet your needs. Also, please note that this is meant to get you started and requires more testing. Alter it as you see fit:

```
Public Sub MakeColumnsFromRows()
    Dim totalCutsToMake As Integer
    Dim currentColumn As Integer
    Dim currentCut As Integer
    Dim rowsToCut As Integer

    Sheets(1).Activate
    rowsToSkip = 10
    totalCutsToMake = (ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count / rowsToSkip)
    currentColumn = 1

    Dim RowCount As Integer
    For currentCut = 1 To totalCutsToMake
        RowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, currentColumn).End(xlUp).Row
        Range(Cells(rowsToSkip + 1, currentColumn), Cells(RowCount, currentColumn + 1)).Select
        Selection.Cut
        Cells(1, currentColumn + 2).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        currentColumn = currentColumn + 2
    Next
End Sub
```

What this does is it first finds out how many new columns to make, then it cuts from the 11th row in each column down to the last row, then pastes those values after the last column that contains data. It does this until all new columns have been made. Please note that this leaves 10 rows of data per column. To change this to 50 you just need to change the `rowsToSkip` variable to `50`.

Here is the before and after screenshots:

**BEFORE**
[image]

**AFTER**
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. This is exactly what I want to happen but I haven't done much in macros/VBA for excel. Is there a guide or procedure for where I should enter that code? Thank you again!

Comment: You're very welcome. The macro needs to go in the "ThisWorkbook" section of the `Visual Basic Editor (VBE)`. To access `VBE`, you have to enable the `Developer Tab` and, on the left, click the `Visual Basic` button. [Here's some instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737(v=office.14).aspx). If any of this is unclear, please let me know and I will go into more detail.

Comment: Thank you for your help and the guide. I was able to successfully perform the task but unfortunately, I realized that I need a different function performed. Basically, I want the $A$1:$A$50 data moved only once and then have only $B$51:$B$100 moved to $C$1:$C$50, $B$101:$B$150 moved to $D$1:$D$50, $B$151:$B$200 moved to $E$1:$E$50, $B$201:$B$250 moved to $F$1:$F$50, etc... The remaining $A$51:$A$XXX values could be left there but would be preferred if they could be deleted. Is this possible as well?

Comment: This sounds like an entirely new question from the original post. I think you should ask a new question with the correct requirements in it, this way there's no confusion for anyone who comes along to this question. This question is answered, according to you, by my answer. Unfortunately, this is not the answer to your `new` question.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
Sub move()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim r As Range
    Dim columnCounter As Long
    Dim rowCounter As Long
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")


    columnCounter = 1
    rowCounter = 51

    Set r = ws.Cells(rowCounter, 1)

    Do While r.Value <> vbNullString
        ws.Range(r, r.Offset(49, 1)).Cut ws.Cells(1, columnCounter)

        columnCounter = columnCounter + 2
        rowCounter = rowCounter + 50

        Set r = ws.Cells(rowCounter, 1)
    Loop
End Sub
```